# Last day of previous month in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0, functx

Is it possible to get the last day of the previous month in XSLT? I found this function: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_last-day-of-month.html but I'm not sure how to use it to get the previous month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
current-date()
  - xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', day-from-date(current-date()), 'D'))
```

**This produces (when evaluated on any day of May 2012):**

```
  2012-04-30-07:00
```

Comment: For some reason "current-date()" cannot be found as a valid XPATH/XSLT function... Would you know why this is so?

Comment: @racer: Most likely you are trying to evaluate this XPath 2.0 expression with an XSLT 1.0 processor. From the fact that you mentioned using FunctX I concluded that you are using XSLT 2.0. It is extremely difficult to produce the same result with pure XSLT 1.0 -- simply because XPath 1.0 doesn't have any date/time processing built-in. In case you are limited to XSLT 1.0, then it is reasonable to use extension functions (EXSLT if available, or your host programming language -- if not).