# Last day of a month or a year in XSLT

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, xquery, bpel

i'm having some issues to make this work on a transformation in Oracle Bpel
I receive a date, and a group criteria: mm/yyyy or: yyyy.

So, I have to construct an 'start day' and an  'end date' with the date I receive.

if the criteria is mm/yyyy,  the start day will be the first day of the given month/year, and the end date, the last day of the given month/year.

I know there is a function called: [functx:last-day-of-month](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_last-day-of-month.html)

But  I cannot make this work in Oracle Bpel, so that's why i'm using this answer: [Last day of previous month in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483246/last-day-of-previous-month-in-xslt)
Just want to know how to do that with any given month.

Example:
for the given date: 2012-10-20T20:18:33

I should return the dates:

Start date: 2012-10-01

End date: 2012-10-31

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: It is not necessary to calculate the last day of month/year in order to group records by it.

Comment: as it's a grouping criteria so the first will be 1 and the last will be 31 .. as you want dd while .. 1<= dd <= 31 .. Am i got what you want ?!!

Comment: Are you saying you're constrained to use XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k : with those dates, have to build a query for another service, it's not a sql or xquery.

Comment: @MichaelKay : don't know what version of xslt i'm using, it's oracle bpel in jdev 11.0.6 http://i.imgur.com/DpKqNHo.png

Comment: @MuhammadHamed what with those month of 28,29,30. guess it's not that way.

Comment: Why don't you show us an example of input and the requested output. -- You can determine the XSLT version by `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>`.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 are so vastly different that you really need to know which version - and more particularly, to tell us which version if you want to ask questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your processor supports only XSLT 1.0, you can determine the last day of month of any given date by calling the following named template:

```
<xsl:template name="last-day-of-month">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:param name="y" select="substring($date, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:param name="m" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="cal" select="'312831303130313130313031'"/>
    <xsl:param name="leap" select="not($y mod 4) and $y mod 100 or not($y mod 400)"/>
    <xsl:param name="month-length" select="substring($cal, 2*($m - 1) + 1, 2) + ($m=2 and $leap)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($y, '-', $m, '-', $month-length)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Example call:

```
<output>
    <xsl:call-template name="last-day-of-month">
        <xsl:with-param name="date">2012-10-20T20:18:33</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</output>
```

returns:

```
<output>2012-10-31</output>
```

Example call:

```
<output>
    <xsl:call-template name="last-day-of-month">
        <xsl:with-param name="date">2012-02-15</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</output>
```

returns:

```
<output>2012-02-29</output>
```

---

### Added:

For completion, in **XSLT 2.0** you can do:

```
xs:date($given-date) - xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', day-from-date($given-date) - 1, 'D')) + xs:yearMonthDuration('P1M') - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
```

Comment: That's a good response, I have to test all those expressions, but seems to work properly, thank you.